# Azure API Management - Problem with OAuth2.0 Client Credentials Authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I'm attempting to set up an API that will use Azure API Management to get a list of users in an Azure AD B2C directory. Through Postman I'm able to make the following request to get a bearer token, with which I can query the endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users:

```
POST /{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 182

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
```

However, when I try to configure this same thing using [Authorizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authorizations-overview), I get the following error:

`Failed to acquire access token for service using client credentials flow: IdentityProvider=oauth2. Details: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90014: The required field 'scope' is missing from the credential. Ensure that you have all the necessary parameters for the login request.}`

This makes sense, as I never configured the `scope` property. However, `scope` isn't a property I can define for the `Client Credentials` Grant Type:

[image: Client Credentials Grant Type]

Where do I define `scope`? Is it defined in the app registration?

**UPDATE 1:**

Some small progress. Rather than using the OAuth2.0 Identity Provider, if I use the Azure Active Directory V1 version, I'm able to get an auth token, using the following settings:

[image: Azure Active Directory V1]

However, despite specifying the tenant id, when I test my authorization using the `get-authorization-context` policy, the access token that I get back indicates the wrong issuer - it doesn't issue it for my requested tenant, it instead issues it for the common tenant.

Anyone have any thoughts on why this would be happening?

**UPDATE 2:**

Alright. Looks like I got it working. I'm not entirely sure why the first update failed, as the solution seemed to work when I tried it again. The only change I made was to remove the "/.default" from the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the end, the solution was to use the Azure Active Directory V1 Identity Provider, using the following settings:

[image: Azure Active Directory V1]

The only change I made from the above picture was to remove the "/.default" from the resource.

Answer (score 0):

maybe when you choose another grant type, there would be a scope field appear. I didn't have a test but based on [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authorizations-how-to-github#step-2-configure-an-authorization-in-api-management).

[image]

Anyway, when using client credential flow, there's no scope, because the scope we always set as `xxx/.default`, just like what [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow#step-3-obtain-an-access-token) showed. Anyway, you need to follow the document to `expose an api, add roles, then add the api permission`. You can only have one App registration which means the app used to protect web api(exposing api) is also used for authentication.

Comment: Hey Tiny, the problem is that I need to get a different scope than that default. As indicated in the Postman query, the scope I need is "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default". However, I will validate how it is configured in the Expose an API section.

Comment: Yeah so I confirmed that the expose an API is properly configured. The document you listed references accessing by policy, which I think isn't what I'm looking for. I'm tryin to access the graph API, and not a specific B2C policy.

Comment: what you want is setting the APIM to call graph API? If so, maybe [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1080606/azure-apim-making-calls-to-microsoft-graph-(azure) can help.

Comment: So, I updated my original post to indicate I did get past the first barrier using the Azure Active Directory v1 Authorization provider. However, it doesn't seem to be using the tenantId I configured. Any idea why that would be the case? I can't see a way to apply any transformations, or get any debugging info at all, with respect to what the Authorization is doing.

Answer (score 0):

To use application permissions with your own API, you must first [expose the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis) by defining scopes in the API's app registration in the Azure portal. Then,  [configure access to the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis) by selecting those permissions in your client application's app registration. If you will not configuring same as application ID URI in Azure AD then is an expected behavior and you will get error `AADSTS500011`.

Create an azure AD account and do the app registration. Generate the `client-secret` .

[image]

[image]

For creating scope

[image]

If you choose Authorization code option while creating the Authorization you will get scope which is optional to enter.

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/authorizations-how-to-azure-ad) and [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token) too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

login with OAuth and then only proceed or else you will be get "This connection is not authenticated" error

[image]

[image]

[image]

`scope` parameter in the request should be the resource identifier (application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the .default suffix like `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

You can refer to this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/protecting-apis-in-azure-api-management-using-oauth-2-0-client/ba-p/3054130)

Comment: Hi Ikhtesam - to be clear, I'm referring to the Client Credentials Grant type, which doesn't offer scope as a parameter to configure. I will try to validate the Expose an API part, but given it works in Postman my guess is that is already configured.

Comment: Hey Ikhtesam, so yeah I validated and the Expose an API part is properly configured. As you mentioned in your link to the oauth2 grant flow for client credentials, you need to specify scope, which doesn't seem to be possible when configuring that through APIM.